# Rotate image hosted on Amazon with Rmagick and Fog

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, carrierwave, rmagick

I am using Carrierwave in my Rails app to handle uploading of images.  This works great.  Sometimes a user may upload an image that is rotated the wrong way.  I would like to add buttons to rotate the images clockwise or anti-clockwise.

I found this post http://www.dzone.com/snippets/image-rotator-rmagick-and-ruby which explains how to do it on a local file but I was wondering how I could do this with a remote file hosted on Amazon with fog?  Could anyone give me and example of how to manipulate an image already uploaded to Amazon with Fog?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to apply that method to your current system?

Comment: you could also use css in css3 compliant browsers  `transform:rotate(90deg);
-ms-transform:rotate(90deg); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform:rotate(90deg); /* Safari and Chrome */`